# Aptana go to last open editor command

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and am looking for a command that will take me to the previous editor I was in (a la Netbeans ctrl-tab or Eclipse's ctrl-F6). I've tried several commands with promising sounding names but none of them seem to behave properly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Windows->Preferences->General->Keys` and have a look at the key binding you have set for the commands **'Next Editor'** and **'Previous Editor'**. Type those commands in the filter search box to save yourself having to scroll.

On Windows the shortcuts for next and previous editor are in fact `Ctrl+F6` and `Ctrl+Shift+F6` respectively, which also happen to be the defaults in Eclipse. So if your key bindings for those commands are not set then you can set them here.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, it's actually 'Next Editor' and 'Previous Editor' I was looking for (as opposed to 'Next Editor (Aptana)' and 'Previous Editor (Aptana)', which somewhat surprisingly are two different commands). These actually have the same default shortcuts as they do in Eclipse (ctrl-F6 and ctrl-shift-F6) which in retrospect I should've tried. (If you wouldn't mind changing your answer to reflect that I'd be happy to accept).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Glad you found what you're looking for!